# Why I can't play the MP3 Base64 string neither way?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3

Here are all the code:

```
// jQuery is loaded already
var s = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,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';

// failed 1
var a = $('<audio>');
a.attr('src', s);
try{
  console.log(a[0])
  a[0].play();
}catch(e){console.log(e)}

// failed 2
var sound = new Audio(s)
sound.play();
```

The both ways are failed. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks,

Comment: Your base64 string doesn't look to play anything audible.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid base64 encode of an mp3 file, check to make sure it is valid. Decoding it back to binary I do not see any mp3 header in it

Comment: I have tried many different online encoders and that's just what I got. And I can play the decoded mp3 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MP3 data is invalid. If you decode the base64 data and load the result in your browser, I doubt you'll hear anything.

If you replace the data with something valid, then it should work. Here's an example:

```js
var s =  'data:audio/mp3;base64,//uQZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' + 
'AAAAAAAWGluZwAAAA8AAAA4AAAp9QACBQUHBwoKDxMTGBgcHCAgJSkpLi4yMjY7Oz8/RERKS' +
'lBVVVpaYGBlZWpvb3R0eXl+goKHh4uLkJCUmpqenqOjp6essbG1tbq6v8TEyMjNzdLS2Nzc4' +
'eHm5uzs8fX1+vr9/f8AAAA5TEFNRTMuOThyAksAAAAAAAAAABQwJAbATgAAMAAAKfXcScCrA' +
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' +
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' +
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' +
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' +
'AAAAAAAAAAA//sQZAAP8GUAPpAAElANIBegACIAAVABEgAASVAvgGLAAAgGAJAP/////8QO3' +
'qdw//////+o4+H6hgQDEEP/////XqS6vRfFv/////1LzL0ixOTIKgg//////bgwKUXPEYSV/' +
'X6X1Z3/+xBkCYzQbwBDiAEQCAiF+KAAAm+B1AMSQABAIC+AYcQACAQQzNEAEgH/////uoUpF' +
'q4vHBMP/////66yz9qjbiff1NuoNr/////+lz17lmyaEh/////+W64DdiBCTQf/////77elo' +
'v/7EGQTDdAqL8WAABP+C6AIsAACTYGIAQ4gBEAgLoAiBAAIBK1Yna4ADMeMbvjjf13/6+VgA' +
'UP0AE/ROAAhEI/c68JBn60Z+++gD5KvM00yEH/////25QBbligxEKAsBBUOiW32dug0//sgZ' +
'CCAAUchQZUEYAINwAhRoAgAinDHK7k5AAAAACODACAAAAAAaagDXgyOzB9C/rcWSHP3YVIP3' +
'91EkgPhS9lqjAAVwVgT5bTas+owEjGOLwNx2V9a6KRPDIiDxzhZv+/yBCBw2QPocFKB8aoA0' +
'hVRMAHzREtJALdZjczqtKXAnf/7QGQKAGG3LMzPJGACDoAYWOAIAIeksTUkmGnINIAhLACJM' +
'BcsnAjTO8bauViEfm5E3+3UvF6KRTxedAELjQjYWlDgltG0AUAAActZ/////v7GOvNgfJUyh' +
'AGDqNCbRtNAENji08nSwGMMCSZ5OPqH3zX9bODrellO1MAlq42DOk4VISMa3Qj0NAXMugusU' +
'T3pgAQBHOf/////o7ZSwP0AIEgCLKIDYapAQCADZtOAsGUwvXEL//tAZAsA4ekoTeEmGeIO4' +
'BhjACIAB7S5NCeYaMgogGIMAIgARsIO3JqDzjj0+dzUI8qIwIftFMpqe45wEFhu0EJHLoRqf' +
'q1q92oFgAAwAf//////jlUC58IooBlQ1WMmQq9kHL2zHg5pYMoCsN0ckV8wNeIqECNAY/TRA' +
'+lUhYoLCLtztdxwimos3DgeHHu+UHMmxcbQQEmgD///////pXUlAHCAAPHrnlsGClBQV/ZRy' +
'411lYb/+0BkCghh2jBOsewZUgsgGHIAAgAHPHNDJJhPSDIAYewQCACl0+SEOEvqdps1J24R5' +
'asZniYqdk8rWq6GvVBJWFQRn2GHuLmEfEJABwP//////s5K0qBX8uByqE42BwrZGpRBM3KGD' +
'BJt8SFp5/7t7PMIM23BSsZrbT9PWQnIs5U7Y4JwTlGC7+V06cF6tCUoAAwv//////rtFG5hA' +
'QgYiCA1JS65BDqLEeEpAnAiaOcBwER/d//7MGQMgPIEIdBJ7DKyCeAYogACAIe4vUuHsGcAG' +
'oBjAAAIAkpMmzF6wS1fM+d+juRJsY81zd84Q5PSDrqF7u2EQSo0QaRQ+tOdBWABgP///////' +
'RIkgIAESvfA1e+MsI8//4FQ2b2XicAMHixgMgtBgjir+2yER/yqIA1MkV4zi6Tpo6F/u2WjJ' +
'BR6qFFCfog7xn///////6HUBv/7QGQBAOHQJ1VpJhq6EGAYfAQiAAe4rV3lpG7oKQBhBACIA' +
'AkGuSNoAMMqypUJ7TrEA9vUggwY+0JbBN1e3NZTTckQOfDaGWbMInykMZTmMG6OEvuEqHaR3' +
'yUnwAAAAAAMATv/////+rxc9RkAEKIkTXXSwABqlnuCQ1VDcbG/7kYOn/XxwGEr21WW9+mr7' +
'ksbyyVFIwQZlWCI65EXZnR+t3wZJY8IPFdHo//////+lq7HQKqw//tAZACA8bUQU+DMGPIMw' +
'AggAAJMBxybV6S8ciArgGDAAIgAAAAkX3wAxJe6JhJy86nJyBPbAHguZUzYyIg07B4/EVwqM' +
'bdeqUpJv3V0zes9xCPZkih+ubxf/////+XLLtFTQXBxXwCJAOVkaIAHUmEHSDUfPqoRJn/SC' +
'wkz31iStEfM7bn5hUyfjpOHH0RPXM2ja5ES0scYAqZlAqpyP/////6eWqJzY41VbAbdEf0qA' +
'6ke+xn/+0BkBYBh8BzXYS9CXgrgGKEAAgEHHMVdhhxvOCsAYpAQCATH1RWpgBjIhRUcv0nHo' +
'1xIRfi2rfujoC4ylopUghf4+LUPw8rL6ET0HqWgptXEHfzDQvIGP//////6iS0LIxEIihmqW' +
'AWb1slK/3Xtoa6Fawu5AZFh5iwURrTBFqs6V51rjlENbl/58m7/rCKOVqEV6YxmWgLGaoAAX' +
'//////6uamV6QpHFTrrbAEVuyfSkZXWev/7QGQIAWHnHlZpgTYKC4AIQQAiXAbcnWeEjRS4M' +
'IBhFACIAuJ5IGD5xMphkRcxZdcOffNKamf+aUry9/dM5OICz9ARfInb9cWhcdP1r6HtMAh//' +
'////8LryKKidaHZgiv900t9WwSHr/TEI601/1TNTr0Nx9zwlMrmsc4WymkbgMkfE8/17SOZS' +
'qEh6Rpw2BS+aQgG7//////ZY9oLrWq4sQBVICmNLJyg6uMHNnKgSEy2gSiR//swZAsAYawn1' +
'cmKGzwJYBhxAAIAh3SpYYScbfgsgGKwAAgCupotvNENk+nHI/jHad6Ah2G/X5Sew9Ewxw+wt' +
'gJksYCj/////+tn+xUbLiCKqqQMTYYjKAnNnZIFkY4GNrDQB77SoPQTOnHoeMGMZdKNs8133' +
'gYBS3vEoJkcjC1yUerOeVE3nkEAAIBbv///////VdkNAGTcpGgA//tAZAQA4gEnVmktQ0oLo' +
'BiSAAIAh3DLZ6MpC7AxAGFIAAgCzEnYxSYoZJI7S4LAThpsx8cAy/xxCQPpn3g8IgjprDS/8' +
'8f0QpwDTprtliVmHazbiRGN2o5nzgMADAf/////+jrqUALGVCEUm21AAQwjPZiQaDKqMAP+Y' +
'hwW36SECBqWhkWdFXJCe03UXdk0wOpdJ0z1aQ00Nk65vr225b/as0gP//////csVbTULpWJh' +
'NgBGtP/+0BkAwBh6i1WaXErWg+ACFIAAlwHbKVVpkBrgCSAYaAAiAJwAVshiaYtMmLKqRIDu' +
'Mm20xLoyb91i9UnecIcPsihmc2UtdkdtEwFe2YYR9upRjsTo48fjMCjABYD/////6CrNNCnv' +
'Qk+MuICAAQMdbAEWnzEswCsiUi6gcBphY4azzWJUWUmhsgsWz9RBXV6Wn/5TnWSAz82BtyNH' +
'chZkmODIpoHkAAR///////6FdWAgAEAo//7QGQDAOH5MFXp8htaCeAYsgACAIgQu1lHxMuYJ' +
'wBiBAAAAmgBEbWS2a5aykxWFXFx8AqJUQN31iGoVqTqGTb8co09PBfp3IlkCqVFbMjioW0KR' +
'UKiM9ajqZhxrAAMB///////0Zn0IAQW26AItrX3A0uCtxPd6y8BPn1pJaAnY8nU1Y/m/2RHh' +
'vJg4mYduN8A2a/6yd1se96LPjPhqM1FZOKXgH6FrH//////2vbnZJX4EAQU//tQZAIEYhEg1' +
'FFzG1INwBhjAAIACWTHSU1AdEgxAGH0AAgA2uADm+2uKQqFOS7h6JMgdpCwGxDbOiBRY4z96' +
'0h0iHpp2pmIuE+z84KhLzIC8mdQSc5HPB3aoU1KZ2Q28UaAADAB//////7nI84G0shAEEQAc' +
'+xar2IxGgcWlFqYzwf9uhlZQZkXhBGfKWSEAcupV5FJDdLsCYW00bTYU4abK/NAM55pAnkn6' +
'xLodHT0algx+0sjOp6CZAIABwBv//////+jYlVpgUABARp4Af/7UGQEAOJ4MdPrLTUSDAAYM' +
'QAiAInAu01NQRRIIQBjRAAIBHsM8ZmJU8sKBaeX1Mattupm1jVsQjlm/vKcKLIphMWfdYGc1' +
'Ne4mhCX6/okRWJzW2FdBnrKhC/vz53f18yCUvl6U/cpptIHAj/////9H6yjVvJpXCAABNrAD' +
'De7eNafiQQHs01LhuUNzMZZCB7hx+xnhTkgImWyzCtlyiCNPXdluJEpfbYaIkRxZLgpghqG8' +
'CFU9oS5UR02m2g9Iyzb6bBWx///////tfpVMoD/+2BkAQDiejHU6w9Dsg6gCFMAAkwJ7K1Np' +
'ekHyCmAYUgACADAAYMVlAHP1Vp79qusrVij/LlMYsFJj3X40uJQ7h9vHirWq+APU61eIjAwd' +
'WktThyqmDoeAk6f+xgQ1HA9zSzXNQjUSCOhUOzzVT2pwsAAGAD//////ffc9NC4MmQBgAAAC' +
'FACsMDU5OGAOGy/OVZWKd2DI3l4OA1yfz54oIHlVbKhv/pfA0Rg7WCbqC6n44iL6/iBH3j6w' +
'cC0DaphRxNaoYK9iEdA8SAWVcXMD//////6dOAgAnAgAAZigA52/Zy7hWFic7LqXuNZkJibM' +
'ZlUEXtY1BGADm9rOV5fp4gMLkf/+0BkFYTyayxT00tFggrgGKIAIgCJoMlIzSxWgCCAYkAAC' +
'AL5dwiCr/TWChHLf5vElekxi4KN+SMxDXcc8qKLWeDoWNHgwAMB//////9XqSWICQwOcmd/L' +
'q0yAB1HezwoZQkeaDydkWlrBchmdyhRcFfm3l8UnM8XDEhDH7HvN9AWma9I/MoW7T7nGhs09' +
'rTEBtX1tV4IysjLUHZcMX///////y7iFRAgACZwOdw3qt8cEQ+nr//7UGQHhuKRMlLLTTWAD' +
'eAYUwAiAAnMy01N5Q8AJwBhAAAIANvWp13jKFg2MOAXhoKLOSLRN8Cf3CQTuXwwMNJin6ghT' +
'GsMljoblhWzd5TFBOOUc/AIivsu/nwytudHMy5ludytro0AADQB//////6FH7KEmyQzQBz7/' +
'4c5EwEJSy5TZ3KFR4GSBdapQyOlyrjhQPVdyknreGqxgv3dXuz2+wa8v6m4bCiTT8WL/3MIN' +
'AgbKtfb3WpF0W998JnxdQ4hGv//////9rzAfrWqCgH/+2BkAQDihTJT6NlB8A8ACDIAAlwJL' +
'LtRR+lNCC0AYgwAiABAAIDKUAGOW4Wc6JFDTynueFO1g1+CdBeDdrfMpkkQA0djGjkX5PAZS' +
'Dn/hZvIHhquoZRgh0qmfhlElu0oAWWlvqb+IeQldWQtKqpkvsbYAkB//////fMu2IDr1NC5o' +
'QAAJJYAa9pK5qugCuZyrarc3UweFdtyHrOqmiUIUP7ec33W1GhUHKs/YusJq9mdC6r7ixVZ5' +
'8YElXMOz+e8lHxdHZjpHqpjCzAB//////+hKHKmahGAgAAA1SwBzeG8L2D1iMKpLctdnHXB7' +
'JGGqu2G5nypCimKfrzeWdyVmSRb1rX/+0BkFwDilC5T6yZloAnGOEIAIuJKSLlNJG1nyC2AY' +
'kwACAAcZQfO75hZLvDdqC/4Md7AghoveVOMLVz1XKrZuU77vf8wzMEABIDy+X/++zCCTggBC' +
'ewKhUlZBQCiWXy+gxuSVKQLUTPncpYPs3aQRioKTpfblssprk2YUI2u70+iIZ81Z/zrOb+0V' +
'4i/pQ3YrR87NEL20+udo1GcnWM2qgE4sAMAH//////Yz6ojJUABm4CHBf/7UGQDAOJLLlMwe' +
'kHyCWAYYQAiAIlIuVml5Q0IM4AhRAAJcFsAhZnOWrOfL7qi5cogKUMKjtNuoWFsYt7pZDlhH' +
'wEufPmprwOjuSqxjpen0M/+pEAPphz7Jx7pkTUgUPl7TcaSPNHgR//////0/uWlyAQABC668' +
'AVtYfVzEBTMn70HjAmLv09PY/DRVFczV+pRa7MsU532HUoWNe7TmH3ZYuBLUrz0Exk+mOFxH' +
'SektwExEmGepErnQADH//////3HiyDcSDAqZAGfgdt3/+z/+1BkBATiUy/TMZtB8g0ACFIAA' +
'gAJRKlLLQ2YiCSAYogACAQcA4Zl9fLGtMqJGSQCOURVzJ72uEpmmbYq372Wb0LRw36H+K/Cv' +
'SEIOdP85/j8bTlE0fQ4TzVGpAcgGn5+jDoLGSSAAwH//////90uGUvC7IBSUBY5O29ZYOkHK' +
'5bPY5cyYye2WRAYATGna9R9yWOmvLJqb3+3qSav/2zV78ay35EaGaPyUGrtymoj3+wEeUmsB' +
'ci7mJDTbj2yA//////+/3y1ZAeDgc/Vepjg//tQZASE8f0yUzNNVQAKYBhyACIACOzHRs2NV' +
'sgtAGFAAIgAo+W+vTvef8yehk3txhuHcb4OMFY2QVKGrZY4Kfcu6jhroqnnMqV6qn2LMZ0m+' +
's4C1ujX9HNLqADgf//////9s8lEUCA5dm8+8pnBDEiHozW1zXDnWdflMidMyqOqpEDw7F+7O' +
'zueNOnlnr3GKALHYa1k/Ai0PRvmvdyDd+GmMADhMNfXY7spCv//////697krCQfSlWAgABXq' +
'gNFai3sZSgQVzdusBVGcmewlP/7QGQMBMILMlfiSGzcCyZIMQAi4AkIwUrB6QXIOwBgyAAIA' +
'oYDzEcAeET3H+PfgbZccUsGqOK7hksYw/0pJ5akhLcNsovRah2QoomyIUf19O9Xr0YTowhCK' +
'2kDQNst6GhJvJqbGvhK09CNmLHG6MIp+dpRhqHXJ2q8GHKEEQKe4hrquoH/utjf/jq1vGE3e' +
'lsS3eW54CoDhRtbtZehxMacACA//////1UZ0mWDhNCaGDAASgmg//tQZAME4ewx09EaOdIK5' +
'jhCACLiyJC5SyXpB0g4AGGMAIgACsas2wGoCNUWeFeYX2Yi6g+7cNzvfrFQ2UVBagULcd8st' +
'GMLtML7nTfr9GO1fIastAIr/rNoRkAAgP/5V8pAB4AaxAR7WAzapdJgoYYHL5f3eVKyo0kga' +
'bNzaTLrv1xERIwpiAcb+0/ECDjVbWW6n4nmG/r8YOt27qBW6m9SgGCOm/0W1pweYAP//////' +
'e62Gy5IGCFkMAmlIAsQJnjkxqxTfnhXaQY2ALBHAv/7QGQLgMIDKtPIWkHoDgAYYQACAQgww' +
'2empRJ4NgBiRACIBDl/DWoEGosYuQFb1LSsrNeV+/PCG8rPv73pTB5I7iuDkRO4gJkFn0xVI' +
'If//////QJxwTSDQTHO0CgASSRtgBmafNqyUjxR6wmZRUrzhBFCgqF41AirbeE724mcfVRy0' +
'WzOazK4hVl8U68EzdFlA+CNXuao621MBhYcf/////4uippVaVgZSjIBAAK7GSwBz8eb//tAZ' +
'AWA4fkrVWsJLKgMgAiCAAJdB3yrX4esrvgsACIIAAkys8oFl8l3/vUTC3Uz5XS8/W3iV2/A6' +
'PMNT/3Jy1hNq0kTKa5NEI3NZBev0ZWVVIoJ0mHtDAAEB//////jPsy5MKqQCAAP6WA13ulYt' +
'eGh1EMt/7DcNZOf94SIdVHmlaYeo4fPIK2/0Rs2qskoapdGYpDblGi46OFSbCEITBYD/////' +
'/+tcCXBWnmhQEbJImwBWWD/+0BkBQDh8jFaaWNFTgpgGMEAAgEHkLlRLAyzaCwAIMAAiTB6c' +
'62EbVKv4BalGfwVkMbvHasxJHwlpKqwrSqfBYQjirVfdAAVW7+f93EUHUmYLjxa6YumAY///' +
'////uepzVtAAA3JgcyywvU224K7+/zLfPC9357IubwyZS55JfUiIt6e8ZTBHofFIsE2RzdBZ' +
'nfzSWd3AQztoaPkNvP//////ZlqJtItCVWWEUAmySNsAZlC3P/7QGQFgOH8MdpowEKODOAYq' +
'QAiAIhgrVXsDNUoIpjiSAGHxL54VyAXg5cz/lBc8sM06rOMSVOVfGjWuYSuL/tGjhHFB8v9j' +
'hq1nMpwsIZt3Vn2caw29C1gwAAABgNv//////0dAogAgABRa2UgBz87mNjOgThu2b/PzqFRE' +
'spMv/PsNuE+c82lFRs5Cid2ILLkx3pzblt6R57CuFc1hX9HONq8zxCpUrABc3v7QkzQG3Iwy' +
'CrJ//tAZAKA4fEyWekHMrwMQBhiAAIAh4SzVaY8bKg5gCFIAAkwImwAmrrDoF8WGvxLLIniE' +
'OQkxDJbZhmjkzHhJ5bC6KiPk4Glnz3Am6r5r7O9u1YmRtWFVmG7mZpmAAQH//////0rVXlyb' +
'hAYAFtbSgA76M/D49gK5Ten5cBtzu+L/pNxBM3WNdTDlTOKhn23MnbmUJlkEfPNo1qMRi41o' +
'haEjNcZWQP/////9fHpEgYFEh0mDYD/+1BkAQDh+StT4wsbugwACKIAAk0IUJlJI2BliCeAY' +
'sQACARAAncsBz8p25YxkxFm3Xyz1nJCGEmhZ87RRLFmaztxftZJkvzciCisQNpLuf27uZcFH' +
'mRbGiI4ekw9lAIGAEgH//////vTamHFEgAH1xgZIUU5KG1EizfJFyxf1AZny8laLc5SXVU8y' +
'He4IOBB0PhnO2wYlyhwmhigplAExA5nVEYYmj7HDaWaC4JYlj//////8gnS8VpxgIAuyOJQA' +
'VvAj6b1Q3hPTYm3vbWD//tAZAsA8hIt1WnmHKoKoBiwAAIBh8ipS4HgZYgjAGDAAIgAYaMRc' +
'+EwnAq4g/4xFb7bOxYYtt+sZmcoXDc2MmA/3MoDGPM19bDjUPvF9Fb///////KXKe0VNFAAA' +
'ARrlAEvIISqqmXcnJ2//9g0xxfLUi/memMWnXQGzsfZCwpZHlC8i18s4TjhRi73BKru7RBB2' +
'UWHpdTT//////9xi2svIAAC2SAVQ/GWBSmE6Mi5apt1mEj/+0BkCgTiDy1RyRkx0AvgGIMAA' +
'gAIDMVETAzTCDKAYYgACAIBiz17efv1j3u+7vnZl/PMLRmt3WSiL7F6izwXMuBqjtp3OnPve' +
'sxtaNcrEjQwAADAB///////9wohVHAxzlPfjzJxiBaGLyPcZ1XS0OXX8qPfP453FGO81yhU8' +
'qwI/Myhju8NH/f4cT31epi8nt2+whlaUmxSffMT7bAf//////cBkgKGRqWVSAXGgseWEIYOZ' +
'//7QGQFifIIJVEQejFiDUAYYwACAAhInUTMjTMILQBggACIAB+F0sc3egcpDPfXud3haSD78' +
'd69JKLKyEah77t6Tp9fPaUJu2EUplGNvkQrg+W0KcBC9JAj5wAAKAP//////y9AtUVDdXMdU' +
'/ZK3y9yOZ/amNXPShprPPL7y2berqsFvhOwoQTGOGMEFJqzWmLKVWYjcTampadJIIpgKflFz' +
'kDKhlz17yCP+r////2XkbaxGB2w//tQZACA4hQu0ssDNLoMgBjSACIBh/SVRsyM0wgkGOFMA' +
'IvBAApYIC9WpZvOhxLAUipyc7l9dogIbSYSPuP+23D04QaGrTYKu/d9mNsstVtkNXCYff5KA' +
'r/fNG6xeW0NYdzaVjcgAID//////2mk+pQAQBzIgWfufYuusVCx5ymot9zstbE6oXN45fhMJ' +
'sY99BxAgyiPVxGZvCP5uTnQ+YuAFKNb6IItRij8stBsBuHk2aAELQvmUxsTShAAAABUrAc1K' +
'bVbDq+RvFA9+qyAyf/7QGQKgOIFJlJjD0JCBwAY8AACAYgovUkh5MWIJJkhCACPwAF5hndRb' +
'ddFG7+byBBtvibFormOIj9oleUlnuVnS6uwgKc5cIILZrRWF6iv///////TTKAAPVUAJZ4TV' +
'UtAyWXT+v1bhgJBkGFP/90qhl7ntKO+v7qwmIem1p7tM6hnrMpfo+M1uaAn/rN+tBTw0eXYj' +
'hcgwG+NiIQ0FRB3wBypgCYDFy0JIUkXVkX5/XaUBw7m//tAZAqE4f0l0bB5QWILoBkBACIBi' +
'MzJQMTkxYAugCBAAIkw56/jhXWnY7u4EUYsY/RlWE557uFSajrs4d3Q82u0QDaKFbzFTojfb' +
'AsIUCH//////oe4XWVmYJQAAdRiNdcp0dUJ0nxhWOPZYKrnOBDecO3tWVE0RrfZKX0JI9mpx' +
'75sXWfPiuVEVLx/sXG/I9Ck7dnaSa9/bfszT/WO1Tf/////8gWN3HaFiaogAACUQaAL263/+' +
'0BkBIRiDjBRUwMssgxgGGEAIgAH2MdAQeRjyCuAYeQACAJHTX5SQgKfwbR3tXaQqXUK5+NjP' +
'SjdB6nPBav8QPzapXJsrWRmidrHst7giuuz3QRoRUYaOLMJzlQQ//////9UKnmNcRWipAALu' +
'Eu1vJCBs6CZ+pXrcEOLV9WuXuZjocC495AUwn6LgtDNQklImgRj1CINdk+gCmQGL+L1vJvUu' +
'nvBbh5ABAW///////2NogIICf/7UGQBgOIYKNAw2RliCwAYgQAiAIgcx0LsGHJIJYBjSAAIB' +
'IBGRafTphxwiqg23qthXBkIsnSYRul3mghdfz28cQaai8NwyIqdgOyYOMfm5nwDBqoGRDATC' +
'gQQ59TluqA8wnAEP//////oJE6TakAIoEQAXvp88qXAdkUThm3vHdx6xv9/l3meFMnn3vb9x' +
'saXJy9pvXIchcuzi+Zv5fUII9BIJcJg0k/r3J7JCYRJAH//////t7tK6kApogwAc12miNyVk' +
'qCi03IuYa4hzGz/+0BkCwjh/RzROw8zkg7AGGMAIgAIuMc+pORliCoAIUgAiAJd8GavRYvu0' +
'cveMu3+MAeVSYd3RRP2MmXSWin3Zk4r+3lejA9Pf6AMIQgAAwAf//////YlAxjYjRAgGUzIq' +
'CwWtikQk1HZ+7fv1woORLWLElxymmatCxaXcDVsXPDVDJoornAwQqhKUrhUBKcxL0hRRAYsg' +
'bMRpwFQJjBRx4yQH//////960Ww/YwsqAE7nNV7tf/7QGQEgeI0MdAzKRyiCkAYcgAAAIhwy' +
'T7MIHJAFxkhBACPwGgKsUGRitn2ZgIKPKiq/Ja/bg6Be7K5XQk2670KrB5qcMNhDztIwAVk8' +
'Rh4Qj59ABYIzIUNaduL+xi4YJlAAID//////+72pgBAFJSy7vZfGASQiJEKmqTkfN5GK09aO' +
'XJikQ/g7LziiAfp0E7G5015wihZsK6U5AbUfGU2v1I4qdFKMEYs41DQV49RfLSL6EwC//tQZ' +
'ACA4iAyTyjZQWAKoBhRACIACSjHQSwk0kgrAGDAAAgAAADYAGaa9YXvT5yrTkzrMzna2scqe' +
's0sIWn+SqWMBmpZ5hy/ZKUaOUmNLqNLm051dKG7RFCAgSPxKj0Z3Wvc9ins1gY//////9OBD' +
'G1MACBUowEHWMr3Ka6DHpR0NDyxloCyp8MsuUkhHmb+pO1sOv212tLgByXsMi00brI5+vMg4' +
'kz338u/w2i05j6ubRYqXyk7xjKQEf//////qXMAQGC6gANRwcICnqCnjP/7UGQFD+JCMU6I2' +
'TF2CoAYwgAiAIjsxzoMINIIM4AhyAAJchrsznYzgABesUu8rS6uvIoh3/59swAe6kYJNGmlX' +
'9MHMunZgWpeTbPU2LL2i8l4yzyHmcqU04Tx8Ds2vSWiwAoD//////8U3aoru7latP6cTrdjE' +
'GTeODRgeOR3NaszDGSNnNLegKwC3crWC9OdRKALtjfHBie48MgGyrh2uPhp7kCZ9e9LPw7J/' +
'SoplY5ZSrAf/////+pRU2/aPBlwAAYESYABgoDRDmz4MXH/+1BkB4DiRy/Q0NhBYgbmGHAAA' +
'n9JNMM8xOUFiDMAIsgACXR/m7H8etDK/hresJ0ibhyLjEEFwocMRWdYWGUi2Z4Rz1S+3z6hq' +
'mIee6osMh7RpY2ySrd4eJQx1ACB10VFeVnHxAggBAOUChtGdiApBTYzmchrxUrWgW/nPZS4v' +
'eUI5ZuPuwKguDIsvuVkfuTCHTdijMagwlRGH3d0jlH6KPJpQ+qM/9htu8emaErUB///////E' +
'aQAWgQL1VCCAiDGiCQBF3SHmBkONxtG/qmC//tAZAoA4icyUuniNIgLYBhjAAIACQjJPMNlB' +
'YArAGHMAAgA70n3S0ENtU4+0GwHXXpYSSzbPbNeFNiKdfw+l7ueP3z+LZhrp5Npi02dbWk0v' +
'LviDAAAUAf//////696wIQAAAQaMRMFdJoHvq401WxFyK63Yz38TGIU46TGiCsDhXNJVLMGz' +
'KdJcyiq5EQqJqJxuOtVSkWSsMCtnveijyBWbem0guLMgwAf//////31uOLVSAj/+1BkAQBiW' +
'jDPMwg1MgkgGFEAAgCIeK9HR+BwSDAAYjQACAABAS3CzUkEQjAPNDnIAwu8TvZdO55SShlRk' +
'AoXe1nl9xoNWozPHhQl63mWVRtsSsItywYQlOJtX2Xi7RraIF6ObJfYtLYLRcGBgI///////' +
'1VyFgoJNJA0ARI79giahARWWLDlxhQqeBuzxTuBEt7ubv58lUsEg7vYMQPLVHqF7QILiKHB+' +
'CJVn6eDBr6ovkwSFgbTePOIAAYALv//////68uqCBAAz4gBbWAb//tQZASFYjMwTyjYMXILo' +
'BhzAAIACWTLOAyhMwAugCGgAIkyqKliHKsxATXs6mpRVtAtE9zvddmoFx07tzoAou8gzWZ36' +
'9qnSoDw2l5DG5tNMAY4nLnxpGJtW2WnO4VtAeAADQB///////+bF5NUqxLUYdI6CYTF33tZX' +
'3whFW7hN4thD2529v2DAQ7ztd8j3FtSBxs1tVqVn2E7Xkno56/eqqIRrYppTIwNNQWpco+Em' +
'rE80ShC1gASPp//////2rSmQgACBABIFF2U/ueiAP/7UGQGAeJYMc9bJlzCDGAYMQAAAIj0y' +
'T8DYMWAOQBgzACIAPCjGrlLfpFEkgX5gC/9uqbgkIv/BtEg3RVrUveqTcXjGd8a7ap7Gugx6' +
'f7XQ62WLHM+Wplk8JstiDHRduWOEAI//////sdf1yCRc2AQIDgg0UWQGyMHZzm4b1LrKfzh3' +
'7VaZsPQYZwf3CpoSGz18z3ibGYYQuoZ/t/Mc9Imkqki4X23b5QQY9q55FNmh8m9+7t82hQB/' +
'/////6XCRVrwfIEKoAAA4giXNiIrGf/+1BkBQDiKzFQwNgxYg6gCEUAAACJ0LVEpLzFyCGAY' +
'wgAiARifFqKfrTdGIXZ+hz6/7miQ6PU7skdhvs01H1p/Det3ZuCsc+7JHr76/7Q5CXc0neQf' +
'RyHQaMzM12dIggAAKP/////9s3PIYfaG0AwAzZ1CMjK5JIA+RiKBSqdzSRyiGhGyWMqXuvF2' +
'NJWzqfOZSSUH7zd4GlrRcXLp6QwyHBIRBABZMmcjudpJmEEQHSOWomEI7Dp69E9sPID/////' +
'//6EQAAKAIgNDYvIUPU//tAZAWA8kUpURjPMPILJjhTAAJ+Rwy1T4SYY6gwAGFAAAgAI8gS5' +
'aXvCRrWPSXYXItxxKZmd2zkQlLZPxnyxuDHPKzMStmKKRNwpIGSJJSWj5jfgKhTLnDktlhWx' +
'H3hOEAAA0AeeuWsxCoHWlALKSSqwAYaAkmmdIEoJsP1sYtFGewLoImjlmrLx7F+iUYFd/mfu' +
'cU93rqTj5eRjYq60iBjpL1t//////+xgyskweGkqgAACRH/+1BkAgjB/jHPyYga8g8gGFIAA' +
'gAIEK0yxjzCiDkAYUgACAAgFrIQfEHZaNlag+cIuxNIYYYVcmlZ7pVp5yre1yc+46ilKGM70' +
'YSm6lLkBAwVo9lZoDedIvaFJgpBbEwBYD/////9lQWY6XUUD9BESADDp8JUbKN0lqSNEa5FF' +
'iWt3NlyJFteZkjnf06OdyMyckaRyjiVPOHJVrV65oSy5IvPqnk4l+ajgK4KhPGgwBIB/////' +
'9bd8Xa21yS9FgANmCgKwCNv/UBXUBXqFeJ///sQZAkN8SYjxZBhLEAOAAghACIAgYQC/AAEQ' +
'AAAACHAAAAEMK4Vv0UOgUvWY2IlZh2GumWPLQD//+X///fFGMcONPWv/////V/qBo8sNFQ0T' +
'EFNRTMuOTguMqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqr/+xBkC4/wAABpAAAACAAADSAAAAEAAAGkAAAAIAAAN' +
'IAAAASqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq' +
'qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqg==';

var a = $('<audio>');
a.attr('src', s);
try {
  a[0].play();
} catch(e){console.log(e)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkIzu.jpg" width="400"/>
```